Korn's inequality for proving coercivity
I'm working with following form of Korn's inequality:
Let $Ω \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be open, bounded set with Lipschitz boundary. Then $\forall v \in H^1(Ω)$: $$|| \nabla v||_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C(||v||_{L^2(\Omega)} + ||\varepsilon(v)||_{L^2(\Omega)}).$$
I want to use this inequality to show that bilinear form
$$
B(u,v) = \int_\Omega \lambda \ \text{tr} \varepsilon(u) \ \text{tr} \varepsilon(v) + 2\mu \varepsilon(u) \circ \varepsilon(v) \ \text{d}x
$$
is coercive. I doneted trace with $\text{tr}$ and $\varepsilon(v) = \nabla u \ \nabla^T u$ (it means: $\varepsilon_{ij}(u) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial{u_i}}{\partial{x_j}} + \frac{\partial{u_j}}{\partial{x_i}} \right)$). Also $\varepsilon(u) \circ \varepsilon(v) = \sum_{i,j=1}^3 \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{\partial{u_i}}{\partial{x_j}} + \frac{\partial{u_j}}{\partial{x_i}} \right)\left(\frac{\partial{v_i}}{\partial{x_j}} + \frac{\partial{v_j}}{\partial{x_i}} \right)$ if I undestand it correctly. $\mu, \lambda$ are the Lame constants.
I'll be grateful for help, because I have no idea how to use Korn's inequality and in the lecture notes there is only that corcivity holds by Korn's inequality. This is a part of proof of some bigger theorem.
